# Create a masking Div

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I need to create with html and css, somekind of a "masking div".
What I want is the following:
[image]

I am using jQueryUI, I want to have the ability to drag the image inside the masking div only, in away that if the image is out of the bounds of the #maskingDiv, that section section will be hidden behind the #maskingDiv.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advace.

Comment: Have a look simple example http://oneblackbear.com/draggable/index.html

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look, that is what I am trying to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have it backwards. The masking div will likely be smaller than the image. The mask will have a fixed width and height and `overflow:hidden` if you'd like to have an `<img />` tag within it. The easier was to do this however, is put the image as a `background-image` of the `#maskingDiv` and apply a offsetted background-postiion

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want some kind of border with your mask? Like a picture frame or something? If you just want to crop the image define explicit height and width and then use overflow hidden.

If you want some sort of masking frame this may work... I've not used the jQuery UI drop and drag, but I'm guessing that a good way to do this would be creating a pseudo element for the element that you wish to drag the image into.

Pseudo elements aren't really in the DOM so should hopefully not cause any problems with your drag and drop.

Something a bit like this...

```
img#drop {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

img#drop:after {
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background:url('mask.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Maybe make a Fiddle to test it out?